# Does $A$ is nonsingular, nonnegative and $A^{ - 1}$ nonnegative imply that $A$ has exactly one nonzero entry in each column?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ be nonsingular, and assume $A$ is a nonnegative matrix (i.e, all $a_{ij}\ge0$) .

Can we say that if the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ is nonnegative, then $A$ has exactly one nonzero entry in each column?

Comment: Do you want to know why it's true in that case, or why it can't be true in any other?

Comment: The inverse matrix **of** $A$ (a.k.a. $A^{-1}$), I presume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are non-negative, and $A$ has two non-zero entries in one column, i.e. $A_{i_1,j}, A_{i_2,j} > 0$ for some indices $i_1 \neq i_2$ and $j$.

Then, since $A^{-1}A = I$, for all $k \neq j$, we have:

$0 = (A^{-1}A)_{k,j} = \displaystyle\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n}(A^{-1})_{k,\ell}A_{\ell,j} \ge (A^{-1})_{k,i_1}A_{i_1,j}+(A^{-1})_{k,i_2}A_{i_2,j}$.

But, $A_{i_1,j}, A_{i_2,j}$ are positive and $(A^{-1})_{k,i_1},(A^{-1})_{k,i_2}$ are non-negative. Hence, we must have $(A^{-1})_{k,i_1} = (A^{-1})_{k,i_2} = 0$ for all $k \neq j$.

However, this means that the $i_1$-th and $i_2$-th columns of $A^{-1}$ are both scalar multiples of $\hat{e}_j$. Hence, the columns of $A^{-1}$ are not linearly independent, and thus, $A^{-1}$ is not invertible, a contradiction.

Therefore, if $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are non-negative, then $A$ has at most one non-zero entry in each column.

Comment: can anybody please elaborate the linearly dependant part?

Comment: If $(A^{-1})_{k,i_1} = 0$ for all $k \neq j$, then the $i_1$-th column of $A^{-1}$ is all zeros except possibly the $j$-th entry. So the $i_1$-th column is a scalar multiple of $\hat{e}_j$ (the vector with a $1$ in the $j$-th position and zeros elsewhere). Similarly, the $i_2$-th column of $A^{-1}$ is also a scalar multiple of $\hat{e}_j$. Since these two columns are scalar multiples of the same vector, they are not linearly dependent. Does this clear up your confusion?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.